# how to login from the iphone to my rails app?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I've my rails app using authlogic for user session, I'm building an iphone-app as client of this site, how can I do with the login\logout\session management?

I know that's a common question but I've tried to look for it everywhere but I can't find anything clear and useful

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can handle through http authentication, and your server sends back a session cookie which is accepted by the `NSURLConnection` object. Nothing special in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can just mimic the browser behaviour. When your user go to the app and want to login, you can ask the server side for a session. Then, user logins, in your server side, remember the session as already loggined.

Now, you use this session as the way to idenfity the user on the iphone side.